# Avoid Windows authentication depending on the controller or URL with WebAPI

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I am using with WebAPI with Windows Authentification.

However, for a very specific case (a Flash Client... no comment), I need one of my controller to accept a non-authenticated client. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [AllowAnonymous attribute in your controllor or methods](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-allowanonymous-attribute-and-authorize-attribute)